# Is there a way to delete record on Salesforce 1(Mobile)

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, community, salesforce1-app

Is there a way to delete a record on Salesforce 1 platform. I know there is a way navigate to sObject but if please someone could help to delete a record.

Currently what i am doing to delete a record on Desktop based application on javascript side is

```
window.location.href = '{!URLFOR($Action.Quote__c.Delete,Quote__c.Id)}';
```

But is there a way to do the same on the mobile platform using sforce.one??

Answer (score 1):

sforce.one doesn't allow you to navigate to the delete page, but you can delete a record through the dropdown on the record detail page:

[image]

If you are in a Visualforce page or publisher action, you can delete the record using [Visualforce Remote Objects](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_remote_objects_using_delete.htm) or a combination of the Apex delete method and a Visualforce action/JavaScript remoting method.